# Why am I seeing glitches when using wx.SplitterWindow?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython, visual-glitch

I'm currently using `wx.SpliterWindow` in my wxpython application. When I run the application, the GUI appears fine. However, when I attempt to move the divider between the parts of the splitter window, multiple weird horizontal multicolored glitches appear.  They continue to appear wherever I move the divider. Once I release the divider, the glitches disappear. (I attempted to upload a picture or GIF of this behavior, but the glitches disappear too quickly to be captured. If I'm able to make a picture or GIF , I'll post it.)

Here is the code I'm running:

```
import wx


class Panel1(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent=parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour((0, 0, 255))


class Panel2(wx.Panel):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent=parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.SetBackgroundColour((0, 255, 0))


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        panel1 = Panel1(splitter)
        panel2 = Panel2(splitter)

        splitter.SplitHorizontally(panel1, panel2)
        splitter.SetMinimumPaneSize(20)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(splitter, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


class App(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        editor = Frame(None, title='wxPython')
        editor.Show()
        return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App(False)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Is this behavior a know bug when using wx.SplitterWindow on certian platforms? I couldn't find anything on [wxPython's issues page](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues).

Here are my specifications

- Windows 10.0
- Python 3.6.1
- wxPython 4.0.0b2

Comment: I can only guess that maybe calling `SetDoubleBuffered(True)` on `splitter`, the panels or the frame itself may help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @MichaelButscher. Unfortunately, it didn't work. I'll keep looking around the wxPython docs though. Maybe something will turn up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug,just set flag `wxSP_LIVE_UPDATE`.
In [DOC](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_splitter_window.html),this flag will

> Don't draw XOR line but resize the child windows immediately.

In python, just write this
`splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(self, style = wx.SP_LIVE_UPDATE)`,then it will perform normal.

Comment: Thanks @obgnaw, Your that worked perfectly! I'm not very well versed in the wxPython library. I guess I missed that part of the docs. I'll award the bounty after the minimum bounty period of 1 day is up (about three hours from now).

Comment: anytime @ChristianDean It's from wxWidgets's DOC,maybe that's why you miss it.

Comment: I also see the issue in C++ application, see my report here: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/wx-users/f-KzNnrjKZ8/pxIJ8F1XAAAJ and there is also a screen shot. Only one line is shown. Do you see the XOR line(as you said the glitches) shown correctly?